# Is free extensions works on Magento 2 enterprise edition?

Tags: extensions, magento2-enterprise

I have installed free extensions on my Magento 2 website which is a community edition. We want to do the same in Enterprise edition. Is the free extension works on enterprise edition.

Looking for your reply.

Comment: try to find in enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sometimes they works but it's not 100% sure that they will work.

You can try to install that extension, might be possible it will work.